# Unable to send the GCM registration ID to application server

Tags: android, cordova

I am implementing android push notification. I could create the cordova/phonegap app using Intel XDK and made all the setup on GCM. I can see my application showing the registration id when I install the app and story is smooth till this.

Now I want to send the registration id to my application server that I hosted. I have already written the rest api which can receive a get and save the registration id. Now the issue is when ever I add the Restful call in onNotificationGCM of index.js, the apk installation shows error "There was problem parsing the package". Please find my onNotificationGCM call code

```
onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "http://XXXX.com/mycloudapp/register?regid="+e.regid;
                console.log("Regid " +url);



                 req.open("GET", url, true);
                console.log("After req.open");
                req.send();
                console.log("after send");
                alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
            }
        break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
        break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
    }
}
```

if I remove the below code from above, again it works fine

```
req.open("GET", url, true);
console.log("After req.open");
req.send();
```

Your help is highly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At last I could solve the issue. The issue is nothing to do with the coding, but Intel XDK project configuration for white listing the external domain. Please follow steps below

1) Select you project
2) Go to the Build Settings and expand
3)Goto Access List box
4) Keep * and select External
5) Add Another access list entry
6) Provide the external domain URL select internal

This worked for me very well.